# Como clonar/baixar um repositório apenas com o último commit?

Tags: git, github

Li há um tempo atrás que é possível clonar um repositório de maneira mais performática apenas baixando o último commit, ou seja, baixar o repositório sem alterações prévias de outros commits.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a *switch* `--depth`:

Exemplo:

```
git clone --depth=1 <url_do_meu_repositório>
```

Veja porém que essa prática de *shallow copy* (estilo SVN) não costuma ser a melhor solução no mundo Git por uma série de motivos:

- O histórico de um repositório é fortemente compactado (espaço em disco não costuma ser um problema)
- Operações de clone de repositórios remotos podem demorar um tempo sim, mas não costumam ser corriqueiras (eu geralmente clono um repositório remoto uma única vez; se precisar de mais clones, faço clones locais).
- O Git também possui ferramentas como `filter-branch` e `purge` para diminuir o tamanho de repositórios muito grandes.
- Alternativamente, se você realmente precisar, é possível clonar uma única branch:

  ```
    git clone -b minha_branch --single-branch <url_do_meu_repositório>
  ```

---

**Fonte:** [SOen - Using git to get just the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision)

Comment: Bem completa a resposta!